# Java ADF application don't read data correctly from oracle 9i DB with ISO8859-6 encoding

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, encoding, oracle-adf

I created an application in Jdeveloper and Oracle-ADF framework with JSF page extension.
The connection is oracle 9i Database with ISO8859-6 encoding
when i run the application it shows the data incorrectly like this

```
"أجازة غٍد اف�ظر    "
```

any body can help to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the compiler encoding in your project properties.
Also check the character set setting in your JSF page.